# how can i change with timestamp mysql in a date

Tags: mysql

I have here MySQL code for my table but I want to change this date but I do not want time but just date what should I do I have already searched a lot on the internet but still found nothing. and I also have a week overview here how I would apply that.

I hope you can help me

regards stefaan

```
    ``-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.4.14
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Dec 12, 2017 at 10:59 AM
-- Server version: 5.6.26
-- PHP Version: 5.5.28

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `phpcurdpdo`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tblusers`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblusers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Auditeur` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `Zone` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `NOKOK01` char(11) NOT NULL,
  `NOKOK02` char(11) NOT NULL,
  `NOKOK03` char(11) NOT NULL,
  `NOKOK04` char(11) NOT NULL,
  `Bericht` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `PostingDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Week` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tblusers`
--

INSERT INTO `tblusers` (`id`, `Auditeur`, `Zone`, `NOKOK01`, `NOKOK02`, `NOKOK03`, `NOKOK04`, `Bericht`, `PostingDate`) VALUES
(1, 'Stefaan', 'Zone 2060', 'NOK', 'OK', 'OK', 'NOK', 'graag een verandering', '2017-12-12 06:27:53');


--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `tblusers`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblusers`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tblusers`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblusers`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=7;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: "I have here MySQL code for my table but I want to change this date but I do not want time but just date "  If you also store the time you can simply change `timestamp` into `datetime`.  Besides why don't you want to store the time you already did it before with timestamp..

Comment: If you want to store a date, then use a `DATE` data type, instead of `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: yes @TheImpaler i also would have suggested using `DATE` datatype but offcource `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` does not offcource work on that datatype not sure if the topicstarter needs to have a default there..

Comment: I have tried it, there is no date anymore

Comment: if I do date then I get to see this 0000-00-00 and when I do datetime I get to see this 0000-00-00 00:00:00?

Comment: hello someone can help someone?